# При попытке задать тип поля ENUM в mysql workbench отображается ошибка "could not set new data type. The given data type ENUM()..."

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Проблема:

Не могу задать тип поля ENUM таблицы в визуальном редакторе mysql workbench. Как это сделать? Помогите пжта

Описание:

Создаю модель базы  данных в mysql workbench. Выделил таблицу, во вкладке "columns" создаю поле, ввел название поля, задаю тип поля как ENUM(). Система mysql workbench ругается:

`"could not set new data type. The given data type ENUM(). Contains error ana cannot be accepted. The previous value is kept instead".`

Тип поля как ENUM не удается задать.

Comment: Создайте поле (а то и всю таблицу) запросом, делов-то...

Comment: @Akina, хорошо, попробую. А причина то какая этой проблемы?

Comment: А фиг знает... какой-то косяк, не иначе. Или в софте, или в Ваших действиях. Судя по описанию - скорее второе. Похоже, что поле  уже существует (возможно, уже создано с дефолтным типом), и изменение его типа сбоит. Попробуйте задавать имя поля последним, а также отключить автокоммит.

Answer (score 1):

ENUM, BIT и SET должны содержать по крайней мере одно значение при вводе этих типов данных в MySQL Workbench. Для этого необходимо перечислить ваши значения через запятую внутри скобок ().

Пример:
ENUM('1','2','3')

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-columns-tab.html